# How to serve tomcat's specific port as url?

Tags: tomcat

I have an application on tomcat on address `http://myserver:8080`, but I want it to be server on specific url, e.g. `http://myserver/jira`. So I want everything that starts with `myserver/jira` to be mapped to `myserver:8080`:

`http://myserver/jira` => `http://myserver:8080`

`http://myserver/jira/Dashboard` => `http://myserver:8080/Dashboard`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Do you already have apache listening on port 80? If not, you can just change tomcat's configuration in server.xml to change what port it listens on.

If you already have apache running, you'll need to use mod_proxy to proxy requests through to port 8080. Atlassian has lots of great documentation on how to dothis, but feel free to reply if you need more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Apache Tomcat connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) to forward requests from httpd to Tomcat.